# Capitalize first word select option

Tags: css

Is there a CSS-only way to capitalize only the first word of select options?

I have tried several combinations but all without success

```
select
  text-transform: capitalize
```

capitalizes all words.

```
select::first-letter
  text-transform: capitalize
```

does not seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unforunately no.. while it can be used to text-transform, The ::first-letter selector can only be used with block-level elements.

Which are like: p
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6
ol, ul
pre
address
blockquote
dl
div
fieldset
form
hr
noscript
table

Option isn't a block level element.

But this is easily enough to do in javascript or a server side language if your able to use that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.